# Automated process to export PowerCenter Workflows as XML

Tags: repository, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Currently we export workflows from PowerCenter Repository manually one by one.
I was wondering is there any process / or can we have a script that can read workflow names from a .txt file and export those workflows as XML and save it to some location.

Our Infa Server is on Unix.

Any help /suggestions if we can achieve this highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use pmrep to list all workflows, then loop over the list and invoke pmrep objectexport, e.g.:

```
#Specify folder name:
FOLDER=`<FolderName>`

#Get list of all workflows:
 WORKFLOWS=`./pmrep listobjects -o workflow -f ${FOLDER} | grep workflow | sed 's/workflow//g'`  

 for WORKFLOW in $WORKFLOWS; do  
      echo "[INFO]: Processing Workflow ${WORKFLOW}"  

      # export single workflow  
      ./pmrep objectexport -o workflow -f $FOLDER -n $WORKFLOW -m -s -b -r -u ${EXPORTDIR}/${FOLDER}_${WORKFLOW}.xml  

 done
```

Comment: Thanks @Maciejg we are working on something similar. Will update if any progress.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it’s possible

Create your own shell script that executes the ‘pmrep’ command multiple times. Personally I would create a query inside the repository manager client tool, and then execute that query with pmrep.

Please get back to us if you have further questions.

Comment: we are working on script. i read about Query inside Repository manager sounds good. Have to give a try.

Comment: Good to hear that you are on the right track. The only unfortunate thing is that the query cannot be created from command line and/or exported+imported to XML, but in most cases you can live with that.

Comment: Hi @LarsGOlsen, I would like to export a list of workflows into the same XML. I managed to do this using the queries you mentioned but being the main intent to build the export dynamically it is not the best way because the file produced by the query isn't clear at all (contains a lot of weird IDs) . Is there any other way like passing a list as the -n parameter?

Comment: It is possible to omit the ID’s in the list, so if you know the precise object names an folder names etc, you can build it yourself...